# Reading a play text file and outputting the first act ,scene, and number of times they speak

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, text-files

I am trying to write a function where the input is a file name of a play and it returns the act, scene, and numbers of times the character speaks in the play. So the output values are [int,int,int]. This is my docstring to clear things up:

```
def firstWords(fn):
    """Act and scene offirst words of each character in a Shakespeare play,
    and the number of speeches of each character.

    Params: fn (string) filename of a Shakespeare play,

    Returns: (dict) key = character; value = [act, scene, nSpeech], where
              character := 1st word listed for a character (e.g., BOTTOM) 
              act/scene := act and scene of the character's first words, and
              nSpeech   := # speeches by the character;
              so each key is a string and each value is [int, int, int] list
    """
```

This is the code I have so far It only counts the number of lines, words, and characters in the play.

```
    numLines =0
    numWords=0
    numChars= 0
    with open(fn,'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            wordList = line.split()
            numLines += 1
            numWords += len(wordList)
            numChars  += len(line)
    print(numWords,numLines,numChars)

firstWords('romeo_and_juliet_folger.txt')
```

My test data that I have commented out is `print(d['JULIET'])`. When I uncomment it and run the code it should return [1,3,118] because she first appears in act 1 scene 3 and speaks 118 times. I would need to do the same for any character in the play. I know I have to build a dictionary using a for loop. Could someone point me in the right direction.

Comment: I would simply use `regex` to parse through the play and match the patterns that I would like, To learn more about this, I found this particular tutorial very helpful: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/chapter7/

Comment: The code you're showing is irrelevant to the question. Furthermore, your question is unanswerable since you do not provide a sample of the input. Please edit your question: (i) add an input sample, (ii) provide the desired output, (iii) show your attempt and tell us where you're having problems.  As a hint, the solution to these types of problems is to first divide the input into chunks that you can analyze further. Dividing the text into chunk ending with `\n` doesn't seem like a natural choice. Try dividing the play into acts, the acts into scenes, and the scenes into each character's lines.